# Unable to solve EADDRINUSE in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to integrate the mailchimp OAuth plugin for node (https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-mailchimp/) and I keep getting an EADDRINUSE error and I am not sure what the issue is. I know what the error means I just don't know how to stop it.

My express server is running on port 3000. The mailchimp class evidently wants to spawn a server - it defaults to port 8100. I have tried changing both of these ports to no avail. What could be the issue?

Here's the route code I am using:

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
  var MailChimpOAuth = require('mailchimp').MailChimpOAuth;
  var MailChimpAPI = require('mailchimp').MailChimpAPI;

var options = {
    clientId: '00000000',
    clientSecret: 'abcdefghijklmnop',
    serverUri: 'http://localhost',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost',

};

var oauth = new MailChimpOAuth(options);
```

Now my initial request works and any subsequent ones cause the error - probably encountering the already spawned server. Is that a bug in the mailchimp class that is should see if it already spawned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're creating a new `MailChimpOAuth` on every request, so when your second request rolls around, you've already got a server listening on 8100.

You need to do all that setup stuff *once* at initialization and, in your request handler, refer to the *already instantiated* `MailChimpOAuth` instance.

As a general rule, if you find yourself doing a `require(...)` in code that runs more than once, your logic needs rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

just run:

`killall -9 node`

and try it again. It worked for me